# Expected answer is 222 but output is different

Tags: c

I have made a program using the below initialization

```
int j=35,l;
l=~j;
```

if `l` is printed as `%d` then the output is -36

Comment: Could you please explain why you expected the output to be 222?  Walk us through your logic.

Comment: binary of 35 is 00100001,its complement is 11011110 whose decimal equivalent is 222.If the above explanation is wrong then please guide me to the right answer.

Comment: binary of 35 is 00100011

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you mean 220, as in this case:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char s = 35;
  unsigned char u = 35;

  char is = ~s;
  unsigned char iu = ~u;

  printf("~35 (signed) = %d\n", is);
  printf("~35 (unsigned) = %d\n", iu);

  return 0;
}
```

Where that prints:

```
~35 (signed) = -36
~35 (unsigned) = 220
```

Remember that `int` is often 32 bits or more, not 8 as you expected.

Comment: warning for the char all depend if it is signed or not, for gcc/g++ a char is unsigned, producing 220 in both case. Use `signed char `  to have -36

Comment: `int` is in fact guaranteed by the C standard to be at least 16 bits

Answer (score 4):

The bitwise compliment operator `~` inverts **all** bits of its operand.  So assuming an `int` is 32 bits, the binary value:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00100011
```

Becomes this after applying `~`:

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11011100
```

Assuming negative numbers are represented in two's complement representation, this value is -36.

The value 222 you were expecting looks like this in binary as an `int`:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 11011110
```

So it seems you were expecting that only the least significant byte gets inverted, but instead the bits in all bytes get inverted.

Comment: Note also that there is a one-bit error: `11011100` vs `11011110`.

Comment: @zwol Correct.  It matches the inverse of what OP *though* was the binary representation of 35.

Comment: Right.  OP made two mistakes, but your answer makes it sound like there was only one.  That's all I was saying.

Answer (score 1):

220 is the unsigned value representing the negation of 35 when stored with an 8-bit data type.

`int` is guaranteed by the C standard to be *at least* 16 bits, so you will *never* produce the value of 220 by negating an `int` containing 35. Use `uint8_t` in `<stdint.h>` to store the value of 35 and its negation.

Also note that `printf`-family functions promote `%u` and `%d` arguments to `unsigned int` and `int` respectively, so you may want to chop off the higher bits with a bitwise AND when printing.